# AttributeError: 'HelloWorld' object has no attribute 'say_hello'

Tags: python

I'm trying to learn some python through the tutorial in beeware in order to create an app for my thesis.

I'm at the step "Update and run in one step" at tutorial 4 and I have to replace a section of my code.

I have to replace

```
def say_hello(self, widget):
    self.main_window.info_dialog(
        'Hello, {}'.format(self.name_input.value),
        'Hi there!'
)
```

with the new code

```
def say_hello(self, widget):
if self.name_input.value:
    name = self.name_input.value
else:
    name = 'stranger'

self.main_window.info_dialog(
    'Hello, {}'.format(name),
    'Hi there!'
)
```

With the first one it works flawless but when I replace it gives me the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/alessio/beeware-tutorial/beeware-venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/toga_gtk/app.py", line 102, in gtk_startup
self.interface.startup() 
File "/home/alessio/beeware-tutorial/helloworld/src/helloworld/app.py", line 25, in startup
on_press=self.say_hello,
AttributeError: 'HelloWorld' object has no attribute 'say_hello'
```

I don't understand why and as soon as I try to modify something I get an indentation error

The entire code is

```
import toga
from toga.style import Pack
from toga.style.pack import COLUMN, ROW


class HelloWorld(toga.App):
    def startup(self):
        main_box = toga.Box(style=Pack(direction=COLUMN))

        name_label = toga.Label(
            'Your name: ',
            style=Pack(padding=(0, 5))
        )
        self.name_input = toga.TextInput(style=Pack(flex=1))

        name_box = toga.Box(style=Pack(direction=ROW, padding=5))
        name_box.add(name_label)
        name_box.add(self.name_input)

        button = toga.Button(
            'Say Hello!',
            on_press=self.say_hello,
            style=Pack(padding=5)
        )

        main_box.add(name_box)
        main_box.add(button)

        self.main_window = toga.MainWindow(title=self.formal_name)
        self.main_window.content = main_box
        self.main_window.show()

    """def say_hello(self, widget):
        self.main_window.info_dialog(
            'Hello, {}'.format(self.name_input.value),
            'Hi there!'
    )"""
    
    
def say_hello(self, widget):
    if self.name_input.value:
        name = self.name_input.value
    else:
        name = 'stranger'

    self.main_window.info_dialog(
        'Hello, {}'.format(name),
        'Hi there!'
    )   


def main():
    return HelloWorld()
```

Comment: My guess is that in your new code the code is not indented. Indentation is very important in python, and so it probably thinks the if statement is not part of the function.

Comment: Please make sure the indentation in your question matches the actual indentation of your code. Put triple backticks (`\`\`\``) on a line before and after the code to format it properly. I would edit, but I'm not sure what indentation _you_ are using.

Comment: The indentation is incorrect. Indent `say_hello()`  function so that it is inside the class definition.

Answer (score 0):

The sayhello function should be in the class
Code:

```
import toga
from toga.style import Pack
from toga.style.pack import COLUMN, ROW


class HelloWorld(toga.App):
    def startup(self):
        main_box = toga.Box(style=Pack(direction=COLUMN))

        name_label = toga.Label(
            'Your name: ',
            style=Pack(padding=(0, 5))
        )
        self.name_input = toga.TextInput(style=Pack(flex=1))

        name_box = toga.Box(style=Pack(direction=ROW, padding=5))
        name_box.add(name_label)
        name_box.add(self.name_input)

        button = toga.Button(
            'Say Hello!',
            on_press=self.say_hello,
            style=Pack(padding=5)
        )

        main_box.add(name_box)
        main_box.add(button)

        self.main_window = toga.MainWindow(title=self.formal_name)
        self.main_window.content = main_box
        self.main_window.show()

    """def say_hello(self, widget):
        self.main_window.info_dialog(
            'Hello, {}'.format(self.name_input.value),
            'Hi there!'
    )"""


    def say_hello(self, widget):
        if self.name_input.value:
            name = self.name_input.value
        else:
            name = 'stranger'

        self.main_window.info_dialog(
            'Hello, {}'.format(name),
            'Hi there!'
        )


def main():
    return HelloWorld()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! It worked but Iḿ not sure why...I tried all the possible indentations...